# Adding sheet2 to existing excelfile from data of sheet1 with pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am fetching data from web into an excel sheet using pandas & able to save it to sheet 1, now i want to fetch a column data into sheet 2 of same excel.

When I am executing the code it still doesn't create a new sheet in the excelfile, just overwrites the existing sheet with new name & desired data.

I have created two functions , first function create the excel file with desired data & function 2 to fetch the column values & create new sheet with that column values

This is Function 2

```
def excelUpdate():
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('Abc.xlsx')
df = xls_file.parse(0)
data=[]

for i in df.index:
    x=df['Category'][i]
    print(df['Category'][i])
    data.append(x)

table1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
table1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Categories')
writer.save()
```

Also I want to get the count of a particular category in sheet 2.
Please help

Sample data

I have highlighted the data which I want in sheet 2 & I want the count of each Category in sheet 2 with category name

```
Index | AppVersion  | Author    | **Category**  | Description   | Rating | Text  
0     | 1.15        | Miuwu     | **Slow**      | Worthless     | 1      | Worked fine while I was home, a week later and 3000 miles away nothing!!
1     | 1.15        | abc       | **Problem**   | Self-reboot   | 1      | No such option.
2     | 1.15        | Rax       | **Design**    | Self-reboot   | 1      | No such option.
3     | 1.15        | golo7     | **Problem**   | Self-reboot   | 1      | No such option.
4     | 1.15        | Marcog    | **Problem**   | Self-reboot   | 1      | No such option.
```

Comment: Can you add sample of data (3,4 rows) and desired output `table1`? Also use `table1 = df[['Category']]`, loop is not necessary.

Comment: @jezrael I have updated Sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openpyxl`, the library `pandas` uses for `xlsx`, to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Abc.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Abc.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
```

Then, with your `table1` ready:

```
df['Category'].value_counts().to_frame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Categories')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. can you please help in count of each Category in sheet 2 with category name

Comment: IIUC you just want to extract the complete columns `Category`? See update.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for, your question title asks for adding data to a second excel sheet without overwriting but there is also another issue about `.value_counts()`? However, your example has quite a bit more info than just category counts? See update for `.value_counts()`.