# Adding Keyword with count of occurrence in sheet2 to existing excelfile from sheet1 with pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am fetching data from web into an excel sheet using pandas & able to save it to sheet 1, now i want to fetch data of a particular column into sheet 2 of same excel but want to put only the Name of Keyword & number of times that keyword appear in that column

For Example ,I have a column with Title as Car Manufacturer in sheet one & there can be multiple rows with different data but same Car Manufacturer like many customer can own Audi,Ford etc & there are 6-7 columns in sheet1 & Car Manufacturer is one of them . I want to get the data like

```
   Manufacturer Count
 1. Audi        100
 2. Ford        30
 3. Mercedes    25
 4. xxxxx       9
```

in sheet 2.
Python code samples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575008/adding-sheet2-to-existing-excelfile-from-data-of-sheet1-with-pandas-python) on adding data to a second excel sheet. Perhaps you can address there any issues around the `to_excel()` part.

On the category count, you can do:

```
df.Manufacturer.value_counts().to_frame()
```

to get a `pd.Series` with the `counts`. You need to convert the result `.to_frame()` because only `DataFrame` has `to_excel()` method.

So altogether, using my linked answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Abc.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Abc.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.Manufacturer.value_counts().to_frame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Categories')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494637/stefan), using `value_counts()` over the designated column would do.

Since you are saving multiple DataFrames to a single workbook, I'd use `pandas.ExcelWriter`:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file_name.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)    # this one writes to 'Sheet1' by default
pd.Series.to_frame(df.Manufacturer.value_counts()).to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

Without necessarily using `openpyxl`. As noted in [`to_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) documentation,

> If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be added to the existing workbook. This can be used to save different DataFrames to one workbook

Note that in order to use `to_excel()`, the `Series` (returned from `value_counts()`) must be cast to a `DataFrame`. this can be done as above (by `to_frame()`) or explicitly by using:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Manufacturer.value_counts()).to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
```

While the first is usually a bit faster, the second may be considered more readable.